# How to avoid hard linking Frontend assets In Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-roo, jspx

I am new to spring MVC coming with experience using PHP MVC frameworks and ROR. I am having a hard time finding the appropriate way to organize and include front end assets into the view templates.

Here is the default code Roo produces for the default style sheet:

```
<spring:theme code="styleSheet" var="roo_css"/> 
<spring:url value="/${roo_css}" var="roo_css_url"/>  
<spring:url value="/static/images/favicon.ico" var="favicon" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${roo_css_url}"></link>
```

This seems totally unnecessary to me. We are calling a variable from the spring:theme code list. Assigning it to a variable in the view scope/ and then calling that view variable for the

Ideally I would like to have some path tokens like: ${imagePage},  ${stylePath}, etc. That we could drop in and use for soft linking.

Hopefully somebody can point me to some quality SpringMVC documentation or give some examples. Thanks

Update:

I have seen a few examples and engfer has posted one below that suggest using the spring tags within the html to ouput the href like so

```
<a href="<spring:url url='/about'/ />">About</a>
```

This would be acceptable however I am getting the following error from jetty

```
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/footer.jspx(6,22) The value of attribute "href" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Am I missing something with the encoding? or DTD?

Update:

So apparently the in-line href style only works with .jsp files as .jspx (What im using) is strict xml. What are the benefits of .jspx over .jsp and

Comment: Spring's reference documentation is a great resource in general for SpringMVC stuff though they lack specific sections on the various tags: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided from Roo is a little unnecessary. If you look at the Spring MVC documentation as tkeE2036 pointed out... you will see the themes section http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" type="text/css"/>
```

---

The Spring theme tag gives you the ability to internationalize your CSS/images/js (imagine an image that has the word 'Hello' which needs to be changed for English/Spanish/etc) into separate internationalized theme files that follow the http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html convention and Spring will automatically resolve the correct resource bundled theme.

---

If you still want your `${imagePath}` or whatever, you can use the `<spring:url/>` tag to get your job done.

```
<spring:url value="/images" var="imagePath"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${imagePath}/foo.png" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Apparently the inline href convention is only compatible with .jsp files. I am using Roo which generates .jspx, which is strict xml. :(